# [Apache]Is possible that someone use (public) method of PHP class in my server?

Tags: php, apache, class, security, setter

Could someone easily access method declared as pubblic in a class located on server? What kind of security level are guaranteed by Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Securing the code in a way you mentioned is on your responsibility, not Apache. The public/private/protected keyword has nothing to do with calling the function from outside world. It's about calling it within the project by other objects. 
However you have to keep in mind, that people are sneaky, and will try to hack your system and inject some pieces of code to your forms (like doing SQL injection or other). This way in theory they would be able execute some code on the server, but, as far as I am aware, only in case if you are using `eval()` or similar function. This does not happen in normal circumstances, only if you are trying to make some kind of php sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Unless access to a method is given to end used via some sort of action, then no user cannot access any method of a class.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['iAllowThisToHappen'])){
    (new \MyClass)->runMyMethod();
}
```

Also method visibility has nothing to do with security [PHP Methods visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).